# Why ids and classes doesn't work in this simple html code?

Tags: html, css

I tried with a separated css file and embedding style in html file.
Styles defined for generic elements (body or p) works fine, but when I try to use a style with a class or id doesn't work. I have spent two days with this and I'm frustrated.
I get the code from a learning book.

This is css:

```
.texto1 { font-size: 40px; }
#texto2 { font-size: 50px; }
body {background-color:green;}
```

This is html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Este texto es el título del documento</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
<p class=”texto1”>Mi texto</p>
<p id=”texto2”>Mi texto2</p>
<p>Mi texto3</p>
</body>
```

This is html with embedded style:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Este texto es el título del documento</title>
<style>
.texto1 { font-size: 40px; }
#texto2 { font-size: 50px; }
body { background-color:green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class=”texto1”>Mi texto</p>
<p id=”texto2”>Mi texto2</p>
<p>Mi texto3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please use english and also fiddle? because m not able to understand these lines.

Comment: @Steve Come on, *clearly* the code block was improperly formatted ;) Check the post source before requesting HTML postings, mkay? :p

Comment: replace all `”` with `"`

Answer (score 2):

They don't work because you have "curly quotes" `”` instead of "straight quotes" `"`

Replace the quotes with the proper ones and you should be fine. And don't use a word processor to type code! Consider getting an IDE. Personally I strongly recommend [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as it provides many useful features while being super easy to use.

Comment: Well, that was awesome..how fool i am not to get this..great one..upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using Notepad++, but I copy the example from a book in PDF format. In the future I will be more careful with copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

It is the type of quotes that you are using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Este texto es el título del documento</title>
<style>
.texto1 { font-size: 40px; }
#texto2 { font-size: 50px; }
body { background-color:green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="texto1">Mi texto</p>
<p id="texto2">Mi texto2</p>
<p>Mi texto3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy and paste the above code and it will be working.

I replaced **”texto1” to "texto1" and ”texto2” to "texto2"**. Please watch the [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/thsg2vyh/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now is working.

Answer (score 0):

hi Juan Carlos Garrido,

you can try like this also.i its working.you need use ( "id or class name")this quation.not curly quotes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Este texto es el título del documento</title>
<style>
.texto1 { font-size: 40px; }
#texto2 { font-size: 50px; }
body { background-color:green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class=texto1>Mi texto</p>
<p id=texto2>Mi texto2</p>
<p>Mi texto3</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now is working.